# Multi Taxonomies same terms

Tags: taxonomy, terms

Is it possible to have multi taxonomies that shares the same terms ?

What I would like to achieve :

I have a taxonomy which contains all the languages as terms. Then I have second taxonomy called native language and a third called second language. I want all of them share the terms of taxonomy language and not to write again the languages for the others taxonomies.

Is there any other way without using taxonomies ?